# Two ICEfaces panel positioned interacting

Tags: icefaces

How do you constrain the elements of a PanelPositioned so they can only be dragged within the current panel? I have two vertical lists of different data types, one above the other. Both use a PanelPositioned to allow drag & drop reordering, but the elements can be dragged up and down to the other panel, generating an error

```
<ice:panelPositioned id="dragPanel1" var="dataType1var"
    value="#{displayBean.dataType1List}" constraint="vertical">
    <ice:panelGroup style="cursor:move;">

    </ice:panelGroup>
</ice:panelPositioned>

<ice:panelPositioned id="dragPanel2" var="dataType2var"
    value="#{displayBean.dataType2List}" constraint="vertical">
    <ice:panelGroup style="cursor:move;">

    </ice:panelGroup>
</ice:panelPositioned>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For icefaces 3.0, add a `beforeChangeListener` to the `ice:panelPositioned` element. This listener should then call `event.cancel()` if the `event.getType() !=` to `PanelPositionedEvent`.`TYPE_MOVE` and the `event.getIndex()` and `event.getOldIndex()` are both greater than 1. If it is a move, then it is within panel. add/delete are moving between panels.

For icefaces 1.8.2 (neve used 2.0), you would need to add a listener to the `ice:panelPositioned` element. There is no `beforeChangeListener`. you will need a before list and current list (two copies). Both initialize to same elements when initializing backing bean. The listener, if a move - set before list to current list otherwise set current list to before list. Must be a copy, not a reference.